# Why Springboot devtools not working properly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, devtools, livereload

dev tools working only on main java file(where @SpringbootApplication annotation located) not on other .java files. In all IDEs intellij, VSCode even though build project automatically enabled and allow auto make to start even if developed application is currently running also enabled.

Want to archive live reload in springboot project.

Comment: Try clean & build first. Run the application. Then make a change to a class and save to see if auto reload works

Comment: Still issue not solved.

Comment: Which dependencies are you using in `pom.xml`? You can add them to the question

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
   <optional>true</optional>
 </dependency>

Comment: How about other dependencies? Which spring boot version are you using?